# Jquery Sortable Grid - Customise images and text

Tags: jquery, grid, customization, jquery-ui-sortable

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid

I'm trying to customise this Jquery example.
Ideally I'd like everything to be centred on each grid tile.
name then image..

```
<li><img src="image1.gif">Item 1</li>
<li><img src="image2.gif">Item 2</li>
<li><img src="image3.gif">Item 3</li>
```

This doesn't work and I've no idea how to get it working !

Once I've got that bit working is there any way I can save the order, so if I visit the page later the layout stays.

Is it possible to save the layout and have it look the same for all users viewing it ?

Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the box content you may play with the padding-top and height: example:

```
#sortable li{
   padding-top: 20PX;
   height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but how do I get the text centred on one line and the image centred directly below it ?